# Can Greedy algorithm (egyptian fractions) never halt?

Tags: algorithms, egyptian-fractions

The Greedy Algorithm seems a standard way of computing egyptian fractions, but I can't find any proof that it always halts nor I can prove it.

Is there any algorithm for egyptian fractions that necessarily halts (is always finite)?

Comment: It does always halt, and you can find proofs on the web, here for example: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/egyptian.html#section5

Comment: @GregMartin I fail to see how it was proven in this link. It says "The numerator of the remainder is getting smaller each time. If it keeps decreasing then it must eventually reach 1 and the process stops" which I can see happening, but not that it always do.

Comment: There is no infinite decreasing sequence of nonnegative integers. Therefore any process that produces a decreasing sequence of nonnegative integers must be finite. The last denominator in this finite sequence must be 0, because otherwise the process would produce another step.

Comment: Slight correction : The greedy algorithm terminates with denominator $1$. Note that the greedy algorithm is often far away from the optimal solution , no matter if we want to minimize the length or the largest occuring denominator. $\frac{11}{199}$ is such a case,